# Empty respond when Post data in C#

Tags: c#, http-post

when I post username and password and IP address I got only an empty response.
my C# code is:

```
public async void APILogin(string user, string pass, string ip)
{
    var person = new Userinfo { username = user, password = pass, ip = ip };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var url = new Uri("http://localhost/login/dblogin.php") ;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url,content:data);
    HttpContent content = response.Content;
    string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(myContent, "Info");
}
public class Userinfo 
{
    public String username { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String ip { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get back? What's the response code?

Comment: @faso its got response like : {"message":"success"} or {"message":"wrong password"} or {"message":"user restricted"} or {"message":"Unauthorized"}

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: @faso it is 200

Comment: Then you should be looking not at your C# code, but at your server code or logs. Seems like C# is doing the job it's supposed to. 

If you still think your C# code is at fault, try POSTing to this URL from something like Postman and see if you get the same result!

Comment: `async **void**`?? You'll probably want `async Task<IActionResult>`

Comment: @AmirEslamzadeh Http [response code 200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success) is "Standard response for successful HTTP requests". The PHP application is saying everything was fine and that is wrong

Comment: @Fildor `dblogin.php`

Comment: And of course: Use an injected HttpClient, don't create new ones on each call.

Comment: @faso But that's the service OP is calling. Wait, I guess, I am missing something. Let me read again ...

Comment: `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` - shouldn't this be `application/json`?

Comment: @faso Yep, got it... I was looking one level too high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it is worked.

```
var url = "http://localhost/login/dblogin.php";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            StringContent data = new StringContent("username="+user+"&password="+pass+"&ip="+ip);
            data.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            loginResp apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<loginResp>(myContent);
```